# Hybrid Inheritance Example

Tags: c++, inheritance, variable-assignment

Can anyone suggest any real life example of Hybrid inheritance?

Comment: The term 'hybrid inheritance' is not common (or at least I had not heard it before), What are you referring to?

Comment: I suppose s/he means this one: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_Hybrid_Inheritance_in_CPP (note the C++ tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hybrid Inheritance](http://guides.wikinut.com/Inheritance-and-Its-types/6dfqqlfm/) is a method where one or more types of inheritance are combined together. I use Multilevel inheritance + Single Inheritance almost at all time when I need to implement an interface.

```
struct ExtraBase { void some_func(); };
struct Base : public ExtraBase {};
struct Derived : public Base, public IUnknown {};

...
Derived x = new Derived;
x->AddRef();
x->some_func();
```

Here is an example where `Derived` uses `some_func` from `ExtraBase` (multilevel inheritance) and `Derived` uses `AddRef` from `IUnknown` which is inherited a single time. Surely it is not from a production code, but the idea is close to it.

Comment: Can you give me some real life example where Hybrid inheritance is used?

Comment: You have a class with multilevel inheritance and you need to implement some sort of callback interface - this is from real life.